# Python - exposing built-in enum to layout function

Tags: python

I am building a system where it makes sense to change the transform pivot point when scaling, as pictured here in the editor:

[image]

Is there a way to point to this in my draw function as well? It can be accessed directly as `bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.transform_pivot_point`, and while I could make a separate enum that mirrors and updates it, it would be much nicer if I could use a pointer-property to just get this list and display/update it directly, as I normally would with a `layout.prop()` call inside of draw, for example.

To contextualize, here's a short snippet that illustrates the overall idea:

```
class CH_PGT_helper_properties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):

    scaleType: bpy.props.PointerProperty(\
        type = bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.transform_pivot_point)


class CH_PT_main_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Connector Helper"
    bl_idname = "CH_PT_main_panel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "PCA" 
        
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        CH_properties = scene.CH_properties

        layout.prop(CH_Properties, "scaleType")
```

This throws an error in my register function that I don't quite understand:

```
TypeError: UILayout.prop(): error with argument 1, "data" -  Function.data expected a AnyType type, not str
```

It says it returns a string so I assumed that this is an enum, but `EnumProperty` doesn't work either.

Comment: Hello ! Do you want to use an enum with the same items but used in another part of Blender, or do you want to access this exact information and display it the exact same way ? If so you can simply use `layout.prop(context.scene.tool_settings, "transform_pivot_point", text="", icon_only=True)`

Comment: @Gorgious This was exactly what I was looking for, thank you! Is there a way I can promote your comment to a correct answer, just to indicate that it was answered? I copied it last time, but that felt a bit like taking credit for something I didn't write myself.

Comment: Hehe sure no problem, I didn't write it either, I copied it from the user interface script. You can upvote this answer if you want https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/211706/86891 it should also answer your question

Comment: Hi, @Dave ! Since we have a fix, and your question turns out to be a duplicate, i see no harm in closing it, If you disagree, by all means point out the distinction in an edit, and we can re-open.